# Windows XP: Hard Drive Very Busy After Hibernate

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, hibernate

I've got the following problem with my old WinXP machine (1.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GB RAM, 500 GB HDD):

After a wakeup from hibernation, the HD goes crazy for at least a minute. It's especially bad if the computer was hibernated for a long time. The guilty processes are "System" with a Page Fault Delta of at least 3000 and constant I/O Delta at about 100 and "csrss.exe" with similar values. (I know this doesn't sound too impressive; the highest PF Delta I've seen is about 80.000 after a fresh boot, but it's enough to stop practically everything else).

Is this really necessary? Can I remedy the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a windows machine into hibernation, you dump the contents of memory to disk.  When you come out of hibernation, windows will page fault on every memory read, since it has load that page from disk.  If the memory gets dumped to non-sequential tracks on the disk or something, it's going to have to seek all over the place while state's restored.  This sounsd pretty normal to me.

Comment: MrTuttle is completely right. Your only option is to use standby instead of hibernate: in standby, power is still applied so RAM retains its contents. Also, the time hibernated shouldn't matter too much: you may be looking at a case of expected-results-bias there.

Comment: But I thought if the whole memory was written on disk upon hibernation and restored afterwards, I shouldn't have more PFs than before... or is the memory not copied/restored 1:1?